# How to solve $4^x - 2^{x + 1} = 3 $ for x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We figured that this can be changed to $2^{2x} - 2^x \cdot 2 = 3$, but couldn't solve from there.  Perhaps we are not on the right path?

Comment: from the two answers so far, you seem to be on the right track.

Answer (score 8):

You are on the right path.

Substitute $y=2^x$, you get $y^2-2y-3=0$. Try to solve that and change it back to $x$.

Answer (score 5):

$4^x - 2^{x + 1} = 3$
$$(2^{x})^2 - 2\cdot2^{x}-3 =0,\qquad 2^x=t$$
$$t^2-2t-3=0$$
$$t_{1,2}=3,-1$$
$$2^x=3\Rightarrow x=\log_2 3$$

Comment: If $x$ is allowed to be non-real, for the case $2^x = -1$ you also get the set of solutions $x=\frac{i\pi(2n+1)}{\ln(2)}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.